# Javascript: Reduce timeout value for asynchronous xhr file upload after file has been completely sent?

Tags: javascript, asynchronous, file-upload, xmlhttprequest, timeout

Usually I always find a solution to my questions on stackoverflow, you guys are really great!
But after hours and hours of searching I am still stuck with this problem:

I am programming a browser extension for Chrome/FF which uploads a file to a server via xhr post method. If the server is not responding I want to give the user a feedback that the connection timed out. Therefore first I used a timeout value of 10000 ms because I thought that the timeout only starts counting after the request/file has been completely sent. However, it turned out that on slow connections the upload took more than 10 sec and the timeout event was fired before the file was sent completely. For some larger files the upload took even some minutes and hence I had to set the timeout value up to 5 min. This is however unpractical on fast connections. On fast connections I do not want to wait 5 min  before I can inform the user that the connection timed out if the server was not responding.

Hence I am looking for a xhr solution which should:

1. first sets the timeout to e.g. 5 min during the file upload in order to allow the file to be sent completely also on slow connections
2. sets the timeout to e.g. 10 sec after the file was completely sent in order to timeout the connection if the server does not respond within 10 sec after it has received the whole file.

Is there any possibility to achieve this?

Edit: What I tried so far was:

```
[...]
var originalTimeout = 10000;
xhr.timeout = originalTimeout;
[...]

xhr.upload.addEventListener('loadstart', function(e) {
    xhr.timeout = 600000;
});
xhr.upload.addEventListener('loadend', function(e) {
    xhr.timeout = originalTimeout;
});
```

I did several upload tests and like this obviously the timeout value was changed to 600000 by the upload-'loadstart' event listener because sending the file took usually much more then 10 sec and no timeout event was fired. But thereafter always a timeout event was fired immediately after the file was completely sent to the server. I was able to confirm on the server side that the file was received completely and also the the response was sent. However, the response was not received by the script as the timeout event was fired before.

Any idea would be really appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a `Promise`, specifically the `Promise.race` method, along with the `XMLHttpRequestUpload` object. You can have one promise be a timer, and the other waiting for the `XMLHttpRequest`:

```
var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
xhr.timeout = (1000 * 60) * 5 //5 minute initial timeout timer.

xhr.ontimeout = function() {
  doSomething(); //if 5 minute timeout is done.
};

var xhrUpload = xhr.upload;
xhrUpload.loadend = function() { //when upload is done, move on to 10s server timer.
raceThis(xhr, callback)
}

xhr.open('METHOD', url, true);

function raceThis(xmlReq, callback) {
  var waitForServer = new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
    xmlReq.onreadystatechange = function() {
      if(xmlReq.readyState = 2) { 
        resolve(false); //the moment HTTP headers are sent as a response, resolve
      }
    }
  })
  var waitFor10Seconds = new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
    window.setTimeOut(function() {
      resolve(true) 
    }, 10000)
  })

  Promise.race([waitForServer(), waitFor10Seconds()])
  .then(function(serverTimedOut) {
    if(serverTimedOut) {
      //do stuff if the server timed out 
    } else {
      //do stuff if the server didnt time out
    };

    callback(serverTimedOut) //you can even use dedicated callbacks! 
  })
}
```

This is a crude representation, there are many ways to expand on this but this is the main idea.

Comment: Many thanks for this idea. Just for my understanding: In the code it should say "Promise.race" instead of "Promise.all", shouldn't it? I haven't used promises much so far...

Answer (score 0):

my dear, you can only set the timeout value before the request is sent. you cannot set it once the request has been sent. I encourage you to avoid setting timeout for such requests because you can't guarantee what file size the user will upload. it is a bad practice.

A lot of things can make the request take longer. such as browser tending to hang due to some other reasons like low memory, another is network connection is slow, another is server is taking too long to respond due to a long running script. For devices with fast internet, your callback functions will execute faster, you don't control this, the user enjoys his fast internet and that is it. for others with low speed connections, they know it that there connection is too slow.

You could as well monitor the progress by listening for the progress event and display a progress bar, that would enhance the user experience and make it lively.

i would not advice you to abort request after some interval of time because this is a state changing operation.